# How can I add an underline colour when the user highlights over the webpage text on nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how I could add an underline colour under to the  text of the of the navigation bar webpage the user highlights over exactly like the example the way how it expands out both sides equally. Here is an [example](https://umggaming.com)

Here is my code below.

```css
        body{
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        header{
          height: 10vh;
          background-color: #4D5061;
        }
        nav ul{
          list-style-type: none;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-align: center;
        }
        nav ul li{
          display: inline-block;
          padding-left: 15px;
          padding-top: 3.5vh;
        }
        nav ul li a{
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 14pt; 
          font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }
        #logo{
          padding-top: 2vh;
          padding-left: 20px;
          float: left;
        }
        section{
          position:relative;
        }
        .section1{
          height:93vh;
          background-color: #FFFFFF;
          text-align: center;
        }
        .section2{
          height:50vh;
          background-color: #A59E8C;
          text-align:center;
          color:white; 
          padding-top:23vh;
        }
        .contact_section{
          height:93vh;
          background-color: grey;
        }
        .hero{
          height:750px;
        }
        h1{
          font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
          color: white;
        }
        .container-fluid{
          padding: 60px 50px;
        }
        .bg-grey{
          background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }
        .logo-small{
          color: #000000;
          font-size: 50px;
        }
        .logo{
          color: #000000;
          font-size: 200px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
          .col-sm-4 {
          text-align: center;
          margin: 25px 0;
        }
        .fa-angle-down{
          color: #4D5061;
        }
        footer{
          height:10vh;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
  </head>
  <body>
        <header>
          <div id="logo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt=""></div>
          <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Units</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="section1">

            <div class="hero"></div>


            <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i>

        </section>
        <section class="section2">
            <div class="banner">
                <h1>What I can offer you</h1>
                <p> Feel free to contact me regarding any  </p>
                <div class="container-fluid text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
                             <h4>Availability</h4>
                             <p>You can expect a response with 24 hours of the sent message. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="contact-me" class="contact_section">

        </section>
  </body>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is as simple as using the `:hover` suffix with your selectors to target the hover state of the links. I'd also recommend putting the padding on the link itself rather than the `<li>` so the clickable area is a bit nicer.

```css
        body{
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
        }
        header{
          height: 10vh;
          background-color: #4D5061;
        }
        nav ul{
          list-style-type: none;
          overflow: hidden;
          text-align: center;
        }
        nav ul li{
          display: inline-block;
        }
        nav ul li a{
          display: inline-block;
          padding: 3.5vh 8px 4px;
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
          font-size: 14pt; 
          font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
        }
        nav ul li:hover a{
          text-decoration: none;
          color: red;
          border-bottom: 1px solid red;
        }
        #logo{
          padding-top: 2vh;
          padding-left: 20px;
          float: left;
        }
        section{
          position:relative;
        }
        .section1{
          height:93vh;
          background-color: #FFFFFF;
          text-align: center;
        }
        .section2{
          height:50vh;
          background-color: #A59E8C;
          text-align:center;
          color:white; 
          padding-top:23vh;
        }
        .contact_section{
          height:93vh;
          background-color: grey;
        }
        .hero{
          height:750px;
        }
        h1{
          font-family:'Roboto', sans-serif;
          color: white;
        }
        .container-fluid{
          padding: 60px 50px;
        }
        .bg-grey{
          background-color: #f6f6f6;
        }
        .logo-small{
          color: #000000;
          font-size: 50px;
        }
        .logo{
          color: #000000;
          font-size: 200px;
        }
        @media screen and (max-width: 768px){
          .col-sm-4 {
          text-align: center;
          margin: 25px 0;
        }
        .fa-angle-down{
          color: #4D5061;
        }
        footer{
          height:10vh;
        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Liam Docherty's Digital Portfolio</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      
  </head>
  <body>
        <header>
          <div id="logo">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/60x60" alt=""></div>
          <nav>
              <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Units</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact-me">Contact Me</a></li>
              </ul>
          </nav>
        </header>
        <section class="section1">

            <div class="hero"></div>


            <i class="fa fa-angle-down" style="font-size:100px;"></i>

        </section>
        <section class="section2">
            <div class="banner">
                <h1>What I can offer you</h1>
                <p> Feel free to contact me regarding any  </p>
                <div class="container-fluid text-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off logo-small"></span>
                             <h4>Availability</h4>
                             <p>You can expect a response with 24 hours of the sent message. </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section id="contact-me" class="contact_section">

        </section>
  </body>
  <footer>
  </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: `#Navagationbar ul li a:hover {
        text-underline-position:below;
        color:aqua;
        `I was trying to implement this when you said about using :hover however, I'm not sure how to do it. In addition, what do you mean by padding instead of li?

Comment: Underlines do not support different colors at this time, so a common workaround is to use a border instead. The part where I put `border-bottom: 1px solid red;` is the fake underline.

Regarding the padding, you should pad the `<a>`, not the `<li>`. If you pad the `<a>` the extra space is clickable. If you pad the `<li>` it is not.

Comment: Thanks for the information regarding this, I tried it and it doesn't seem to work. Not saying your wrong it must be because, I'm putting it in the wrong section. Would you mind answering the question with the example of the code to support your answer please? Thanks so much for your help. Furthermore, if I follow the border way of doing it will it come out exactly like the example linked in the forum post? What I mean by this is equally come out on both sides not just when the user hovers over it a border around it straight away comes up.

Comment: I can't view the example you linked because it's blocked by the filters at my workplace. The snippet below my answer contains the modified version of your code that does the border workaround -- look for the line that says `nav ul li:hover a{`

Comment: No problem, thanks I sorted out my issue on my end. However, I wanted the styling of how it appeared to the user in a different way. Therefore, does this link work for you at your work? [link](https://creativegrenade.com)

Comment: I'm not sure which nav you are referring to in that link, but all of those are a lot more complicated than a simple CSS line.

Comment: I'm referring to the homepage navigation bar, in order to replicate this would I use another programming language other than CSS? How would I implement this to my webpage nav bar?

Comment: There are a few different ways to do that in CSS. [Here is one example](http://bradsknutson.com/blog/css-button-with-sliding-background-color/) that uses box-shadow to do the effect. You might also be able to use pseudo-elements to do that, but this method is far simpler.